# How to pass self by reference from within the object being passed?

Tags: c++, c++11

I am confused about the syntax I need to use.

I have:

```
class Foo {

public:

    void bar(Baz& grr){

    }

}
```

Another class:

```
class Baz{

}
```

And:

```
class Jay : public Baz{
public:
   void doStuff(){
        Foo thing();
        thing.bar(); //Here is the problem ? How do I pass this instance to this function ?
   }
}
```

How do I pass an instance of `Jay` to `Foo::bar(Baz& grr)`, from within `doStuff()` ? If I try to use `this` the compiler says to dereference it using `*`. How do I do that ?

Comment: `thing.bar(*this);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing exactly as compiler suggests:

`thing.bar(*this);`

By dereferencing the pointer, you "create" a reference.

Answer (score 1):

`this` is a **pointer** to the current object. You need to "dereference" it to get the object's reference:

```
thing.bar(*this);
```

Answer (score 1):

You dereference by using the `*` operator like so `*this`. Dereferencing returns the pointed-to object and since `this` is a pointer to the current instance `*this` will return the object of the current instance.

Note, however, if you save this reference and that instance goes out of scope it will be destroyed and you will be left with a dangling reference that will cause undefined behaviour when attempted to be read.